# Curl request ignore proxy in php

Tags: php, curl

The following works using a command line:
**curl --noproxy '*' -k -X GET https://xxx:443**

I am trying to run this command in php, I believe I have to ignore the proxy and SSL verification but I am getting a connection timeout error.

This is what I tried :

```php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);      
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://xxx:443');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the port out of the url

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 433);`